# Neo4j Cypher query: perform calculation on relationships' properties during traversing process

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on RPG game, exactly on the exchange artifacts component. I am using Neo4j graph database to store all artifacts and players exchange orders for these artifacts.

Graph diagram looks as follows:

[image]

`:Exchange` relationships represents players exchange orders. For e.g.: Player B is exchanging 1 `Mega Boots` artifact for 10 gold. Player C is exchanging 1 Mega Helmet for 2 pairs of Mega Boots.

So now, I am working on creating cypher query that should provide different paths. Each path should reveal artifact exchange orders sequence, so in the end I will get more gold then I have at the begging.

For e.g.: existing gold amount 100.

Path1: `Gold->MegaBoots->MegaHelmet->MegaSword->Gold`, Number of gold after all exchanges 115

Path2: `Gold->MegaBoots->MegaHelmet->Gold`, Number of gold after all exchanges 111

**Complexity:** During moving between 2 adjacent nodes, query should determine (make calculation on properties of relationship that connects these nodes), whether I have enough resources to get to endNode.

For e.g.:

[image]

Initially, gold amount is 10 and query starts moving from startNode `:Artifact({name=gold})` to it's adjacent node `:Artifact({name=MegaBoots})`. Query sees 2 `:Exchange` relationships and selects only relationship with `id=2`, as it's `baseResourceAmount` property is equal to initial gold amount (relationship with `id=1` is not suitable for as, it's `baseResourceAmount` value greater then initial gold amount). 
Now, query moves from node `:Artifact({name=MegaBoots})` to end node `:Artifact({name=MegaHelmet})` using `:Exchange` relationship with `id=4` as after 1st exchange our resource amount is 2 which is equal to relationship's `baseResourceAmount` property value.

Eventually, the final path will be `Gold--:Exchange(id=2)-->MegaBoots--:Exchange(id=4)-->MegaHelmet`

So, does anyone know how to tell Cypher to make specific calculations on properties of relationships that bridge 2 adjacent nodes?